# How to return a struct by value using JNR?

Tags: java, openh264, jnr

I'm trying to work with the [openh264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) native library from Java code using JNR. The function I'm calling is defined in openh264's C header file to return a simple struct by value:

```c
typedef struct  _tagVersion {
    unsigned int uMajor;
    unsigned int uMinor;
    unsigned int uRevision;
    unsigned int uReserved;
} OpenH264Version;

OpenH264Version WelsGetCodecVersion (void);
```

I wrote the following Java counterparts:

```java
public class OpenH264Version extends Struct {

    public OpenH264Version(Runtime runtime) {
        super(runtime);
    }

    public Unsigned32 uMajor = new Unsigned32();
    public Unsigned32 uMinor = new Unsigned32();
    public Unsigned32 uRevision = new Unsigned32();
    public Unsigned32 uReserved = new Unsigned32();
}

public interface OpenH264 {
    public OpenH264Version WelsGetCodecVersion();
}
```

and finally trying it:

```java
OpenH264 openH264 = LibraryLoader.create(OpenH264.class)
                    .load("openh264");
OpenH264Version version = openH264.WelsGetCodecVersion();
```

However, the returned version has wrong values (and they are different on each invocation).
The lib was x64 running on Windows 10 x64.
I could load the same lib with JNI+JavaCpp and the return values were correct.
What am I missing?

Comment: I have asked similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129984/how-to-return-by-value-from-native-function

My current workaround is returning struct as "@Pinned @Out" parameter, but I am able to modify native code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you need from JavaCPP to be able to keep using it instead of switching to JNR?

Comment: @SamuelAudet, JavaCpp automates much of the process, but still requires native compilation and bundling native libs. But we continue with JavaCpp because of this issue

Comment: Looks like JNR does not support that (because JNI does not support that) as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253872/2519698

Comment: @zakgof Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you're already bundling OpenH264. You could use JavaCPP to generate only the JNI code in C++, and then compile it as part of OpenH264.

Comment: @SamuelAudet, openh264 allows royalty-free usage when your app downloads original binaries on demand.